# Switching between information widgets using buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, qpushbutton

I am creating a main window with PyQT for the automation of a room full of equipment. I would like the window to have a lateral screen which shows general parameters of all the equipment but, when I click a button related to one particular device, this lateral screen would show its particular configurations (like the temperature of a fridge, for example), very much like PyQT's own property editor.

Does anyone knows which widget should I use for this lateral window and how could I link it to other buttons to make it show different information according to the selected equipment? The closest I got to it is the tab widget, but it isn't exactly what I want yet, as I can't put a button that selects the right tab anywhere I want on the screen.

I hope my question is clear.

added mockup images to try and make it clear. The first image shows the lateral menu (as I want it to be) for a room with coffee machine, lamp, deadly laser, and fridge as equipments. As I click one of the buttons, say, the Deadly Laser one, the lateral menu would change to what is shown in the second image: the particular configurations of the laser. And so on for the fridge, the lamp, the coffee machine, etc.

[image: Menu with no particular equipment selected, thus showing general configurations]

[image: Menu with the deadly laser selected]

Comment: Mh, no, sorry, it's not really clear. Can you possibly create a mockup image of what you want to achieve? Also consider that general questions like yours, asking "what could I do to achieve xyz" are most likely opinion based (and such questions are generally closed, as they're off topic to StackOverflow). Finally, the property editor you are referring to is in Designer, and it is part of Qt, not PyQt. That widget is a very specialized QTableWidget subclass.

Comment: @musicamante, i added the images and changed the tags as you suggested, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding: why QTabWidget doesn't work for you?

Comment: @musicamante with QTabWidget, i would have to change tabs by clicking on the tab buttons above the widget. What i want is to change tabs by clicking directly on the buttons of the equipment (for example, the Deadly Laser button on the image).
One example is QT designer's own property window: you dont search for a tab with the name of the object which you want to edit to click on it. Instead, you click directly on the object and the property editor automatically changes to show the properties of that object, without it even needing to show the tabs up there.

Comment: Clicking on a tab isn't the only way to select it: study the documentation about QTabWidget, specifically `setCurrentIndex` and `setCurrentWidget`.

Comment: (1) Use a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) for the lateral widget. (2) Put the buttons in a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) (using the relevant stack-index for each button id). (3) Connect buttongroup.idClicked to stackedwidget.setCurrentIndex.

Comment: @ekhumoro this is exactly what i wanted! Can you submit it as an answer, please?

Comment: @MarcoMontevechi Great! I have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) for the lateral widget. Then put the buttons in a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html), using the relevant page-index of the stacked-widget for each button id. You can then connect the `buttongroup.idClicked` signal to the `stackedwidget.setCurrentIndex` slot, to switch between the pages of your lateral widget.